# Visual studio Xamarin not hitting breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have installed VS 2017, version 15.3.3, breakpoints are working perfectly on web asp mvc projects but not working on xamarin projects, either: PCL, Android or iOS.
(I am on Debug mode) everything is installed in its default setting, I have not changed any project options

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging with the Android emulator, you might need to tick "migrate to physical computer with a different processor version" under Hyper-V manager -> Image -> Settings -> Processor -> Compatibility. This resolves random app crashes and also allows debugging from visual studio to work.

Comment: I am debugging on Device but either on emulator breakpoints are not working

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, and restarting Xamarin Studio / deleting the app and cleaning/rebuilding/reinstalling worked.

Comment: Do you mean restarting visual studio?

Comment: Ah yes, it's Visual Studio now-a-days.

Comment: I solved it however I am using visual studio xamarin on windows

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it, [image]

checked checkboxes was unchecked, now it's working